# using declaration, class pointer.

Tags: c++11

Is is possible to use *using* declarations to parameters within a class when pointing to the class itself? I.e., instead of writing `ptrToSomeClass->someParameter`, `using` can declare the parameter itself: something like `using someParameter = ptrToSomeClass->someParameter`. I understand that this might be bad for readability but, perhaps, sometimes easier on the eye to omit `ptrToSomeClass->` part.

Comment: `auto &someParameter = ptrToSomeClass->someParameter;` ?

Comment: @Quentin Thank  you, just what i was asking for : )

Answer (score 0):

@Quentin's comment is a correct answer:

```
auto &someParameter = ptrToSomeClass->someParameter;
```